# Blazor: Why onchange and onblur event are not both triggered if I set breakpoints in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor

I understand the difference between `onchange` event and `onblur` event. `onchange` will be triggered if you edit the value (different than the previous value) in the text input then tab out the input, while `onblur` will be fired if clicking out the text input. If I create a text input with both `onblur` and `onchange` event binding

```html
<input type="text" @onblur="HandleOnBlur" @onchange="HandleOnChange" .../>
```

then I had handlers as below

```cs
protected void HandleOnBlur(FocusEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("On Blur Call");
}

protected void HandleOnChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("On Change Call");
}
```

In my experiment, I use Visual Studio 2019 to set breakpoints on both functions. If I do not edit the value just click in and click out, only `On Blur Call` is printed in the console, which is what I expect. If I edit the value to be different then tab out, only `HandleOnChange` is hit and only `On Change Call` is printed. Interestingly, if I remove both breakpoints, `On Change Call` and `On Blur Call` will be printed.

I have created my github repro here: https://github.com/Owenll66/BlazorTextInput

Comment: works fine on my end.

Comment: Can you create a small project, share it via GitHub, I want debug by myself, then I will help you. And you need care `StateHasChanged` .

Comment: @DoNhuVy The GitHub repro is here https://github.com/Owenll66/BlazorTextInput

Comment: Result https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/133889552-09c6035e-afa4-4a61-8a99-c32c861d8679.png I see it can call also 2 events. I use VS 2021.

Comment: @DoNhuVy you won't need a `StateHasChanged` if handling events in Blazor in most scenarios as it's automatic. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with running VS debugging with the browser.  The events are firing, the debug interlinking isn't picking both up.

Answer (score 1):

If you change value of text-box, it calls onchange event. If you place mouse cursor out, it calls onblue event. It works as expected.

If you not change value of text-box, just place mouse cursor into text-box, then go out, only event onblur called.

I experiment in my computer with Visual Studio 2021 preview, it always go to inside also 2 break-points. I use Google Chrome `Version 93.0.4577.82 (Official Build) (64-bit)` on Windows 10 pro x64.

[image]

Comment: It sounds could be related to VS? I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.11.3 and Chrome Version 93.0.4577.82 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: My PC is high performance with core i17 generation 10th, and 32 GB RAM, SSD. Seemly, low performance computer can cause delay/lag rendering also Debugging process of DOM by Blazor, and it causes strange behaviors .